# Error Handling in WCF Rest 4.0 online template

Tags: wcf, rest

I keep getting the 400 bad request if there is de-serialization issue / other errors. If i try to debug by setting a breakpoint in the method that gets called, it does not get hit, if there is a deserialization issue. How do I intercept this and tweak the response to give me more details.

I looked at some articles regarding webprotocolexception but I think the WCF Rest online Template and the starter kit or not the same. Is the starter kit like an add-on to the template?

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling Exceptions in RESTful WCF Services is tough. Deserialization issues are the worst since no user code gets called. The framework handles the Exception and simply returns an error to the caller. There is a way to see those errors though. You have to configure tracing for WCF (via Web.config). Here’s a link describing the process as well as where to find the trace viewer on your machine:

[Service Trace Viewer Tool (SvcTraceViewer.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)

Unfortunately there's no way to tweak that behavior. For other Exceptions, though, you can implement a custom `HttpBehavior` (or `HttpBehavior2` if you're using the REST Starter Kit) with a custom `IErrorHandler` implementation to handle the Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 means bad request => it is picked up at WCF level and does not even reach the method. So you need to look at the request and if you are passing JSON, fast chance it is in wrong format.

I had a personal project that I implemented in WCF REST and had to battle with this error which was quite frustrating. Also error handling on the server and returning error codes to the client is atrocious since you cannot return text content and all I have is HTTP error code and error description (first line in the HTTP response). I **will never ever use WCF REST again as it is a bodged implementation.**

Comment: thanks, I am not clear what this means - 'it is picked up at WCF level and does not even reach the method.' I think sanitizing the request before being sent to the service may not be an option since the consumer of the service needs to do this which may or may not happen.  I was thiking anything along the lines of request interception as mentioned here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx. Even I am not sure if its a good idea to continue with the wcf rest online template, thinking about asp.net mvc rest service.

Comment: It means that the request is considered malformed and will not trigger your method in the service. If you show me your request and the service interface declaration, I should be able to tell you what is wrong.